# Addition vs multiplication as binary operators

Tags: arithmetic, recreational-mathematics, binary-operations

It is known that arithmetic operations of addition and multiplication are binary operations that take in two inputs and give out a single output. However, consider the following scenario:

> Suppose I have a jar containing some number of balls, and I give you some balls to add to the jar. If I asked you to add three balls into the jar, then that's easy, you'd just toss em in there. However, let's say I asked you to double the number of balls in the jar, you wouldn't be able to do that unless I showed you many balls were in the jar.

This is sort of strange: We require to know both inputs for multiplication but we don't require to know both to do addition. Why is this so when they are both known to be binary operators?

Comment: I see no difference: you add three balls to a jar with $n$ balls inside: but if you do not know the value $n$, you cannot tell how many balls are inside...

Comment: You describe a physical encoding of addition that allows you to construct $x+n$ without knowing $x$, but not $x\times n$. But consider [levers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lever): physical systems that let you do $x\times n$ without knowing $x$, but not $x+n$.

Comment: Could you explain that lever example? I don't quite get it.

Comment: By constructing a lever with a certain length, you can have the upward force on one end be double the downward force on the other end, even if you don't know what that force is. On the other hand, you cannot build a lever that will have the force on one end be the force on the other end + 2 Newtons, not without knowing the force on the one end.

Comment: Very interesting.

Comment: If I can take the balls out of the jar, I can match one new ball with each ball from the jar, then put them all back in the jar. The number of balls in the jar has doubled. No counting is required.

Comment: That's like stronger than looking inside the jar @nickgard

Comment: As @Wouter sort of points out, this is a question about the kinds of physical systems that can be built. It's more like an engineering question than a math question.

Answer (score 3):

You still won't know how many balls are inside the jar until you look inside the jar. You can't add two numbers when you only know one of the numbers...

Comment: The whut, I'm pretty sure you can toss in a few balls into that jar without looking inside it. The problem is not number of balls but rather multiplying.

Comment: Indeed: in case of $n\to 2n$ you need to know $n$ anyway, while  in case of $n\to n+3$ you can physically add three (balls) but you still need to know $n$ to know $n+3$. Adding $3$ to $n$ without knowing $n$ only makes sense when throwing $3$ (more) balls in a jar, but not if you wanna compute $n+3$ given $n$ :)

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with the operators being binary, but rather how those operations deals with the operands.

Let's assume the jar has $n$ balls, and let that be the left operand. Then, adding $2$ balls to the jar would correspond to the operation $n+2$, while doubling the balls would correspond to the operation $n \times 2$

Now, addition can be seen as a repeated process of adding 1 ball to the jar some number of times. How many times?  Well, that's what the right operand says. OK, but how many each time?  Exactly $1$. So, we know everything to do what needs to be done from the right operand alone.

For example, adding 2 balls means adding 1 ball exactly 2 times. No need to know the left operand (i.e. what's already in the jar).

On the other hand, multiplication can be seen as a repeated process of adding n balls to the jar some number of times. How many times? Again, that's what the right operand says (well, you need to subtract $1$ if you start out with the $n$ balls already in the jar).  OK, but how many each time? Well, that's the number $n$, i.e. th number of balls already in the jar i.e. the left operand.

For example, multiplying the number of balls by $2$ (i.e. doubling the number of balls) means adding n balls to the already existing $n$ balls. So this time, yes, we need to know the left operand.

Comment: I had a similar idea but I couldn't word it as you did, however after reading some of the comments on the post. I thought maybe it's wrong and has something to do with the engineering of the method of multiplication / addition rather than those ideas themself. What do you think of that?